# Is it possible to recover an accidentaly deleted EF migration?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I am developing a new functionality for a project involving a set of changes to the database. The project uses Entity Framework 6 Code First.

I ended my tests and I was about to release code and database changes when I realized I was missing a migration (all source files .cs, .Designer.cs, .resx).

I cannot say for sure how it happened but I must have deleted the files **after** running `Update-Database`.

Now when I run `Get-Migrations` on my development database I get a list like this:

```
//LastGoodMigration
//DeletedMigration => can this be recovered?
//AnotherMigration
//CurrentMigraton
```

What is the correct way to recover from this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution and I feel very dumb after all.

I was wrongly focusing on the task of "recovering" the lost migration files, forgetting about the fact that the current database state after all was dictated by the current entity classes.

So I issued the following command:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration LastGoodMigration -Force
```

Then I deleted all the following migration files and I re-scaffolded a new single migration with a simple:

```
Add-Migration NewAllIncludingMigration
```

Sorry fo the dumb question.